# When I try to kick someone who has higher roles than the bot it fails but sends msg

Tags: javascript, discord, bots

If I try to kick myself or who has higher roles than the bot, it fails but it sends to the person which is mentioned you were kicked. How to stop sending the message when the bot fails to kick.

```
const BaseCommand = require('../../utils/structures/BaseCommand');
const Discord = require('discord.js');

module.exports = class KickCommand extends BaseCommand {
  constructor() {
    super('kick', 'moderation', []);
  }

  async run(client, message, args) {
    if (!message.member.hasPermission("KICK_MEMBERS")) return message.channel.send("Та энэ коммандыг ашиглах боломжгүй.");
    const mentionedMember = message.mentions.members.first();
    let reason = args.slice(1).join(" ");
    if (!reason) reason = "Шалтгаан өгөгдөөгүй";
    const kickEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setTitle(`Та ${message.guild.name} сервэрээс хөөгдлөө`)
      .setDescription(`Шалтгаан: ${reason}`)
      .setColor("#ffffb7")
      .setTimestamp()
      .setFooter(client.user.tag, client.user.displayAvatarURL());

    // .kick @user 
    if (!args[0]) return message.channel.send("Хөөх гэж байгаа хүн ээ бататгана уу. \`.kick @user шалтгаан\`");
    if (!mentionedMember) return message.channel.send("Тодотгосон гишүүн энэ сервэрт алга байна.")
    try {
      await mentionedMember.send(kickEmbed);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(`Гишүүн рүү захидал явуулах боломжгүй байна.`);
    }

    try {
      await mentionedMember.kick(reason);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return message.channel.send("Тодотгосон гишүүнийг хөөх боломжгүй байна.");
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `return` during the kicking part of the code

The code should look like this:

```
    try {
      await mentionedMember.send(kickEmbed);
    } catch (err) {
      return console.log(`Гишүүн рүү захидал явуулах боломжгүй байна.`);
    }
```

Sorry if this doesn't work, I'm still pretty new to coding